# How to make uitableview load many sections at a time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have a UITableView to show pictures ,each picture has a name;for some reason, i have to make the name as a section header,and the picture as a section row,the major code is like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [dataList count];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     ...
      return cell;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
      ...
      return view;
}
```

the picture is as big as 640*640;
my problem is : every time ,the picture will not load until its top shows in the screen;
i want to load many pictures at a time ,but the fact is a picture is loaded when its top shows in the screen;

Comment: I would have `cellForRow...` check where its row is relative to the visible rows and then invoke an "imageForRow..." method for 2-3 adjacent cells.  "imageForRow..." would check if the images were already being loaded, and, if not, start them loading.  Keep the images cached in the dataSource, of course.

Comment: i have the same mind before,but i just do not know how the row is relative to the visible rows;i tried to find if there is some method which method determining when to take the cellForRowAtIndexPath method(i thought it should be the method who determin which cell is visible);; but i am not find out which method....

Comment: If you actually look at the documentation for UITableView you just might run across something to tell you the visibleCells or the indexPathsForVisibleRows.  Or maybe not.  You'll never know unless you look.

Comment: en,thanks,i will read the documentation carefully;it's helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the delegate method that asks you for a cell won't get called until a new cell is about to get into the view, you have to preload images somewhere outside the delegate method.

Comment: yes,i try to make a mutabledictionary to preload cells when the data is added,it works fine!!!now i just need to add some limits to avoid the dictionary take too muck memory!!  thanks !!!!

Comment: certainly! hah,the reputation is hard to get!!